# Button inside a popup window in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the code needed in order to have a button inside a popup window in Javascript?
and then the function of that button is to go to a different page
this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWin() {
        var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        myBtn = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=300');
        myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Name: Esperanza</p>");
        myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Price: P800,000</p>");
        myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Size: 50 sq. metres</p>");
        myBtn.focus();


        function gotoreserve() {
            window.location.href = "localhost/tola/reserve.php";
        }


    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: write the HTML code using document.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin()
{
var myBtn=document.getElementById("myBtn");

 myBtn=window.open('','','width=200,height=300');
 myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Name: Esperanza</p>");
 myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Price: P800,000</p>");
 myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Size: 50 sq. metres</p>");
 myBtn.document.write("<input type='button' value='GoToReserve' onclick='gotoreserve()'>");
 myBtn.focus();


function gotoreserve()
{
window.location.href = "localhost/tola/reserve.php";
}


}
</script>
```

Comment: i have a question, is my coding in href wrong? it seems when i click the gotoreserve button it stays still and does nothing

Comment: btw tnx for helping me out im glad there are people like you who helps the people that are unable to code correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this tricky DOM way,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin() {
    var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    myBtn = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=300');
    myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Name: Esperanza</p>");
    myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Price: P800,000</p>");
    myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Size: 50 sq. metres</p>");

    // Add a button element here
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "im a button";
    button.onclick = "gotoreserve()";
    mybtn.appendChild(button);

    function gotoreserve() {
        window.location.href = "localhost/tola/reserve.php";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have a question, is my coding in href wrong? it seems when i click the gotoreserve button it stays still and does nothing, btw tnx for helping me out im glad there are people like you who helps the people that are unable to code correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWin() {
        var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        myBtn = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=300');
        myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Name: Esperanza</p>");
        myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Price: P800,000</p>");
        myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Size: 50 sq. metres</p>");

        // Add a button element here
        myBtn.document.write('<button onclick="gotoreserve()">Click Me!</button>');

        myBtn.focus();


        function gotoreserve() {
            window.location.href = "localhost/tola/reserve.php";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i have a question, is my coding in href wrong? it seems when i click the gotoreserve button it stays still and does nothing

Comment: btw tnx for helping me out im glad there are people like you who helps the people that are unable to code correctly :)